# Find Expected Value from joint density function

Tags: probability

If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have the joint density function $f(y_1,y_2) = (1/8)y_1 e ^{-(y_1 + y_2)/2}$ for $y_1>0$ and $y_2>0$ and $0$ elsewhere, and $D = 50 + 2Y_1 + 4Y_2$

How would you find the expected value of $D$? I know it would be $50 + 2E(Y_1) + 4e(Y_2)$. I just don't know how to find the individual expected values with this particular joint density.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: from a joint density $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ one can obtain the marginal densities of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ by 
$$f_{Y_1}(y_1) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y_1,y_2)dy_2,$$
$$f_{Y_2}(y_2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y_1,y_2)dy_1.$$

Comment: Ok. Looks simple enough. I'll see what I come up with.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to multiply each integral by either y_1 or y_2? Then for variance it would be (y_1)^2 and (y_2)^2?

Comment: Yes, once you calculate $f_{Y_1}(y_1)$, then you can calculate $E[Y_1] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y_1 f_{Y_1}(y_1)dy_1$ and similarly for the variance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the joint pdf.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(D)&=\mathsf E(50+2Y_1+4Y_2)\\&=50+\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty(2y_1+4y_2)f(y_1,y_2)\,\mathrm d y_1\,\mathrm d y_2\end{align}$